# Get DIV to fill remaining width

Tags: css, layout

I am trying to use CSS to get a DIV to fill the remaining page width, after a fixed-width div on the left (and below a fixed-height header)

The CSS I have is:

```
body{margin:0;padding:0}
#header{height: 100px; background:#ccccff;}
#left {position:absolute; left:0; top:100px; width:200px; background:#ccffcc;}
#main {position:relative; left:200px; background:#ffcccc;}
```

The HTML is:

```
<div id="header">Header stuff here</div>    
<div id="left">Left stuff here</div>    
<div id="main">Main stuff here</div>
```

(head and doctype omitted here for brevity)
When it is rendered, the main div is still full page width, meaning the right-hand edge is 200px off the right edge of the browser. How can I get the main div to fill the remaining width?

(eventually I will want to put other divs inside main, and make their widths expressed in % relative to the main div)

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use position. Use Floats. Float the "left" div left, set its width. Give the "main" div a left-margin of the width of the left div, and set the width to auto.

```
#left { float: left; width: 200px;}
#main {margin-left: 201px; width: auto;}
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/GhtHp/1/

Comment: Note that this will cause `#main` to overflow the page 201px to the right

Comment: @GiantDuck Sorry, width of #main should be set to auto. I've fixed my example

Comment: `width: auto` is good unless the interior divs are less than the full width; if their width in in percent as said in the question, then there are problems. :/

Comment: You might have to break down and just use a two-cell table to get your outer structure to behave nice without a ton of CSS to account for all the weird situations that might come up.

Comment: Thanks for this - it worked a treat. I was able to put more divs inside the main and have their widths set as a % of main which is great!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using positioning which is considered evil, just use floats.

```
#left {float:left; width:200px; background:#ccffcc;}    
#main {margin-left:200px; background:#ffcccc;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WAgz7/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Does this accomplish what you're looking for?

HTML -

```
<div id="header">Header stuff here</div>    
<div id="left">Left stuff here</div>    
<div id="main">Main stuff here</div>​
```

CSS -

```
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#left {
    float: left;
}
​
```

Jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/xzWK5/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's easily possible with CSS calc. Unfortunately CSS calc is only supported in Chrome so far.

Here's a better way:
HTML:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="main"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#header{height: 100px; width: 100%; background:#ccccff}
#main{position: absolute; left: 200px; right: 0; background:#ffcccc}
#left{width: 200px; left: 0}
```

Having `#main` exactly 200px from the left and 0px from the right gives you the full width minus `#left`